# How to iterate JSON object with variable Key name and SubModule as an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How can I save data in JSON format which looks like this:

```
    [
    {"modules1":
        {"noofsubmodules":"2",
         "cmheading":"Chapter 1",
         "submodules":["lesson 1", "lesson 2"],
        }
    },
    {"modules2":
        {
            "noofsubmodules":"1",
            "cmheading":"Module Title",
            "submodules": ["Submodule 1"]
        }
    },
    {"modules3":
        {
            "noofsubmodules":"3",
            "cmheading":"Module Title",
            "submodules": ["L1","L2","L3"]
        }
    },
...
...
    ]
```

Other than using this :

```
for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
    }
}
```

I don't know the number of modules, It depends on client only.
and following Answers on this question and other questions as well didn't help: [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: `p[key].submodules`?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. Do you want to iterate through all submodule in you example  ?

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to to iterate through all submodules in your given example you can do as follow:

```js
const list = [
   {"modules1":
        {"noofsubmodules":"2",
         "cmheading":"Chapter 1",
         "submodules":["lesson 1", "lesson 2"],
        }
    },
    {"modules2":
        {
            "noofsubmodules":"1",
            "cmheading":"Module Title",
            "submodules": ["Submodule 1"]
        }
    },
    {"modules3":
        {
            "noofsubmodules":"3",
            "cmheading":"Module Title",
            "submodules": ["L1","L2","L3"]
        }
    }
];


list.forEach(module=>{
  const key = Object.keys(module)[0];
  module[key].submodules.forEach(submodule=>{
      console.log("submodule", submodule)
  })
})
```